# Why would a God create animals that manifest homosexual behavior if he thought that homosexuality is a sin?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, free-will, animals

There are some people who think that homosexuality is a choice. They would argue that we can make this choice because we have free will. I will focus on those who think this way because of religious reasons. Those who think that God gave us the freedom of choosing right or wrong. But God is also the creator of the animals. So why do most of the animals manifest homosexual behaviour? They do not have free will. They cannot chose, they do not know what right or wrong is, they just follow their insticts. Why would a God who thinks homosexuality is a sin, create animals who have homosexual relationships?

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mammals_displaying_homosexual_behavior) is a list of mammals displaying homosexual behavior and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexual_behavior_in_animals) is the link to the wikipedia article about homosexual behavior in animals.

Comment: Why do you think that "God thinks homosexuality is a sin" ?

Comment: On what ground we can say what God thinks ?

Comment: We have no means of answering why God legislates as He does. His legislation proceeds from the excellence of His nature and thus doesn't rely on any further justification than that.

Comment: This sounds less like you have a genuine question about philosophy and more so like you want to start an argument over this topic, which seems evident based off of the above comments. If we take your actual question as being "Why would a God who thinks homosexuality is a sin, create animals who have homosexual relationships?" then it is very clear that this isn't a quesiton about philosophy and instead just a question trying to get a response from theists. Stackexchange is not a forum or debate site, it is a Q&A site that aims for as close to objectively answerable questions as possible.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, Well, the bible is considered to be the word of God and the bible clearly labels homosexuality as a sin, so what can we extract from that?

Comment: Maybe that the will of God is inscrutable...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, Then what is the difference between the concept of God and any other concept invented by human being that also cannot be investigated at least in principle?

Comment: @Not_Here, I understand this and I am sorry. Actually I want both an answer and a further discussion/debate in chat about the subject.

Comment: @Arthur. God is the very source of normativity and truth, whereas human concepts seek conformity to such standards. It's the difference between original and derivative. By the way, the use of concepts is a tool necessary for our finite minds. It's believed that God doesn't employ them.

Comment: There are different versions of natural law; Bible scholars are divided on homosexuality and the Bible, etc.

Comment: The question is less emotive if generalised and de-theised. It could be - How do theists explain the ability of God's creatures to sin, and what do they mean by sin? It's not a new question.   .  .

Comment: @PédeLeão, how do you know that God is the very source of normativity and truth?

Comment: @Gordon, That's right! I am referring to those who are clearly against it.

Comment: @PeterJ, I think a theist would say that no other creature has the ability to sin. Animals just follow their instinct. The notion of sin applies only to humans.

Comment: @Arthur. Better yet is the question as to how *you* can know that. I think you already know the answer to that, namely, we have to seek reconciliation with God through repentance.

Comment: @Arthur - The notion of sin yes. But is it more than a notion? The way I re-phrased the question avoids making any assumptions about this, or even about the existence of God.

Comment: Flagging this to be moved to Religion SE or Christianity SE, because this is not about philosophy, but instead about religious tenets.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that God made them that way? Couldn't it be just as likely that something else made them that way, or that in some cases (like mammals) they *choose* to do such things? Mammals have the intelligence to make decisions. As for species of lower intelligence, it's probably irrelevant and unwise to attempt to hold them to Human standards.

Comment: Clownfish can also change gender as a matter of fact, though I don't think that is necessarily homosexual behaviour.

Comment: This is a theology question, ask such questions on the stack exchange related to each religious community for their scholarly opinions about it.

Answer (score 8):

In the case of the Hebrew Bible/Old Testament, there is no inconsistency, because sin is restricted to humans. At the bottom [of this page](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H2403&t=KJV) is a list of all HB occurrences for 'sin' (חטאת). Also interesting would be [Gen 6:5](https://www.blueletterbible.org/niv/gen/6/1/t_conc_6005) in the story of Noah:

> The LORD saw how great the wickedness of the human race had become on the earth, and that every inclination of the thoughts of the human heart was only evil all the time. (NIV)

Even though god regrets having made "the human race ... and with them the animals, the birds and the creatures that move along the ground", wickedness (רע) is only reserved for humans (v. 5).

So, abstracting, you see that there does not need to be an inconsistency if you reserve the concept of sin for humans.

Whether the Jewish/Christian god thinks homosexuality is a sin is another issue that is not on topic here.

Comment: Good answer. I was thinking: How can someone who already knows **everything** regret something? It's like he made a mistake and he regrets it. How can God make mistakes?

Comment: @Arthur the idea that the Judeo-Christean god would be infallible originates from the early first millennium CE, while this text is probably around 1,000 years older. The original author did not have the same god-concept. In the HB there are many passages where Yhwh appears as relatively human-like. If you're interested in how people who subscribe to the idea of infallibility deal with a text like this, I think that would make a good question on [judaism.se] or [christianity.se].

Comment: @Arthur. The orthodox interpretation by Christian and Jewish theologians of the phrase "The Lord regretted..." is that it is a figure of speech (*anthropomorphism* is the term usually employed). I certainly don't agree with Keelan's opinion on the matter.

Comment: I try very hard to not let opinion be a part of this discussion. That the idea of infallibility originates in early medieval scholarship is quite clear from the primary texts, assuming that those texts reflect the way the authors thought about their god. That there are many human-like passages is also textual fact; the whole J-source has a very human deity. Yes, you can make the text match your own interpretation by explaining it as anthropomorphism but that does not deny that there is no textual basis whatsoever for assuming the original author thought in terms of infallibility.

Comment: @Keelan. Your interpretation contradicts the authority and inspiration of the Bible as testified by the apostles and Christ himself. For example, "All Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness..." (2 Tim 3:16)

Comment: @Keelan There is nothing wrong with an opinion here, as long as a person can give a reason for their opinion.

Comment: @Gordon well... There should be one objectively best answer. So no, I don't think opinions are always appropriate as long as arguments are given. See the relevant discussions on meta.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is from a Judeo-Christian perspective, as that seems to be the basic perspective you're asking from. I don't know enough about the religions with reincarnation, and your assumptions about animals' lack of free will or rationality may not be true for them.

1. Firstly, sin is generally considered to only be a category that applies to sapient beings: humans and angels/demons. But while animal homosexuality may not be sinful, God could consider it to be *unnatural*, or counter to his designs.
2. A core concept of Judeo-Christian thinking is that the world we know has been holistically corrupted by sin. Humanity was created as a priviledged species, the "image of God", which both means that humanity is the most God-like of all created things, as well as indicating a role of being God's representatives on this earth. Whether sin has corrupted all things directly through the original human acts of sin because of those humans authority overt the world, or whether God more actively "cursed" the world, the result is that the world we know now is not the original perfect world of God's designs.

   An example of plant thorns is given in the scriptures: God is said to have changed plants after the fall of Man by making some of them produce thorns, as a consequence and punishment for sin. So they are both natural from our perspective and unnatural from the perspective of God's original design. But God is still seen to be in control, and it is accurate to say that God willfully makes plants with thorns.
3. So within a Judeo-Christian perspective there is an inherent contradiction between what we observe as "natural" and what God would consider "natural". After sin "natural" has been changed. If God did consider animal homosexuality to be unnatural, it could be seen as one of the changes introduced by sin.
4. In the same way, this makes the whole argument over whether human homosexuality is a matter of choice irrelevant. If human homosexuality has genetic causes, that doesn't tell us anything about whether it is part of God's original design, because it too could be an unnatural change like plant thorns. In my opinion then, debates (within Christianity) over morality of human sexuality shouldn't really be about what is "natural", for it doesn't really tell us anything. But demanding that it is a matter of choice to people who don't feel like they do have a choice is sure to very insensitive and hurtful to many.

Comment: Please provide references to support the claims being made in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the focus you have given, even without questions of right or wrong the underlying choice is to do or not do. All people have this choice in every action in every moment. Staying with the focus, it is not thought that animals have the intelligence to choose to do or not do, free will, as humans do and that they act with animal instinct rather than choice.

Interestingly, the commandment requiring humankind not to sin was given to humankind, not animal kind. It can be argued that the animals do not sin since they do not have either knowledge or commandment upon them. But, anyone practising 'strange animal-husbandry' would be guilty of sin.

Comment: More interesting is that "commandment requiring humankind not to sin was given" **through** humans. So, commandment for animal kind not to sin should be given through animals, maybe?

Comment: @rus9384 If animals have knowledge and have been commanded then, perhaps they sin but, who could judge?